# How to create a PackageMaker pkg that doesn't require admin password?

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker, firebreath

I am trying to create an installer for a Internet Plugin on Mac OS X with PackageMaker. I'm not picky about the tool I use, but it needs to be free. It'd be nice if I could do everything I want with PackageMaker because CMake/CPack supports PackageMaker and the project (build with [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org)) is built with CMake.

The problem I am running into is that I am only installing the plugin for the current user -- in ~/Library/Internet Plugins -- but the installer still insists on asking for the admin password! I have heard that you can turn this off as long as you don't need to target versions of Mac OS previous to 10.5, but I can't find any way to do this.

Am I missing something? Is there a different tool I should use?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your installer asks for admin password might be because of some actions you have in your installation process, for example if you have actions to kill web browsers.

When I built my first installers for my (also firebreath) plugin, installing inside the user's directory, it was not asking for admin password. After I added actions to stop Safari and Firebreath, then my installer started asking for admin password.